# User context in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, authprovider

I'm just getting started with React and i tried to write a simple context that will store the details of the user.

AuthProvider.js

```
import React, {useState,useEffect,createContext } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentUser = {id:1,role:'user'} //here get user from server
    setUser(currentUser)
    }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}  >{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

useAuth.js

```
import {useContext} from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from './AuthProvider';

const useAuth = () => {
    const user = useContext(AuthContext);
    if (user === undefined) {
      throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider');
    }
    return user;
};

export default useAuth;
```

App.js

```
import {HashRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {AuthProvider} from './context/AuthProvider';
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <HashRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </HashRouter>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import useAuth from '../context/useAuth'

function home() {
    
    const { user } = useAuth();

  return (
    <div>home</div>
  )
}

export default home
```

But when i try to use "useAuth" i have error:

```
src\pages\Home.js
  Line 6:22:  React Hook "useAuth" is called in function "home" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".
```

Can someone explain to me what the problem is and how can I fix it?

Comment: components should start with a capital letter: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component

Comment: The lint rule uses naming conventions to tell which functions are components, which are hooks, and which are neither. So renaming the component to `Home` with a capital letter will fix it.